# Find matching sequence between two arrays (pattern matching) C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two arrays, one is a main array I am comparing against, and the second array has a number of integers whose order might be shifted to the right or left and it also might contain default values.

The result (true/false) of this comparison looks like this:

```
x = -9; //unknown number

int[] mainArray = new int[]{3,1,0,1};

int[] a = new int[]{x,x,x,x}; // true
int[] b = new int[]{x,x,1,x}; // true
int[] c = new int[]{x,x,1,0}; // true
int[] d = new int[]{x,x,1,0}; // true
int[] e = new int[]{x,3,1,0}; // true
int[] f = new int[]{1,3,1,0}; // true
int[] g = new int[]{3,1,0,x}; // true
int[] h = new int[]{3,1,1,0}; // false
int[] i = new int[]{x,1,1,x}; // false
int[] j = new int[]{0,1,1,x}; // false
int[] k = new int[]{3,1,x,x}; // true
```

What would be the a way to search if the sequence exists in the main array?
There are two problem I cannot figure out:
1) the array might be shifted to the right or left, but the result is true even if it is shifted
2) the x value which is skipped in comparison

I end up in doing lots of if statements, but I am sure this problem was solved elegantly by someone else.

Comment: Why `new int[]{x,x,x,x}` should return `true`? Please, share what have you tried?

Comment: _second array has a number of integers whose order might be shifted to the right or left_ How many times numbers can be shifted?

Comment: The shift value is the length of the array. Both arrays are the same in length. If the array is the length of 4, then 4 shifts. x x x x is a default condition, maybe for this I can make if statement to filter out. And for others iterating 4 times while shifting to the right and finding the correct sequence between each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting the problem statement correctly, you could try something like this:

```cs
class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int>
{
    private int specialValue;
    public MyEqualityComparer(int specialValue) {this.specialValue = specialValue;}

    public bool Equals(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y == specialValue) return true;
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
void Main()
{
    int x = -9; //unknown number

    int[] mainArray = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 1 };

    var lists = new List<int[]> {
    new int[] { x, x, x, x }, // true
    new int[] { x, x, 1, x }, // true
    new int[] { x, x, 1, 0 }, // true
    new int[] { x, x, 1, 0 }, // true
    new int[] { x, 3, 1, 0 }, // true
    new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 0 }, // true
    new int[] { 3, 1, 0, x }, // true
    new int[] { 3, 1, 1, 0 }, // false
    new int[] { x, 1, 1, x }, // false
    new int[] { 0, 1, 1, x }, // false
    new int[] { 3, 1, x, x }, // true
    };
    var mainRepeated = mainArray.ToList();
    mainRepeated.AddRange(mainArray);
    foreach (var e in lists)
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, mainArray.Length))
        {
            if (mainRepeated.Skip(i).Take(e.Count()).SequenceEqual(e, new MyEqualityComparer(x)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb,s) => (s==x? sb.Append("x") : sb.Append(s)).Append(",")).ToString()); // we've got a match
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Would it be possible to show how to write this line without Linq: if (mainRepeated.Skip(i).Take(e.Count()).SequenceEqual(e, new MyEqualityComparer(x)))

Comment: `SequenceEqual` is pretty much the core or my answer - if you remove it you're going to have to write so much more code. What part of this LINQ does not fit with your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Idea: convert the input to a string and duplicate it, so that it contains shifted variants:

```
{ 3, 1, 0, 1 } ==> ",3,1,0,1,3,1,0,1,"
```

Convert the pattern array to a regular expression. Every `x` is replaced by `\d+`, which means one or more digits:

```
{ 3, 1, x, x } ==> ",3,1,\d+,\d+,"
```

And then compare.

```
string inputAsString = String.Join(",", mainArray) + ",";
inputAsString = "," + inputAsString + inputAsString;

string pattern =
    "," + String.Join(",", input.Select(i => i == x ? @"\d+" : i.ToString())) + ",";

bool result = Regex.IsMatch(inputAsString, pattern);
```

Where `input` is one of your arrays `a` to `k`.

---

Here is a version which tells you by how much the array was shifted. To do this we format the numbers, so that they all have the same length. This allows us to calculate the shift from the position of the match in the input string.

```
const int x = -9; //unknown number

int[] mainArray = new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 1 };

int[][] inputs = new[]{ //        is match, shift
        new int[] { x, x, x, x }, // true    0
        new int[] { x, x, 1, x }, // true    1
        new int[] { x, x, 1, 0 }, // true    1
        new int[] { x, x, 1, 0 }, // true    1
        new int[] { x, 3, 1, 0 }, // true    1
        new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 0 }, // true    1
        new int[] { 3, 1, 0, x }, // true    0
        new int[] { 3, 1, 1, 0 }, // false
        new int[] { x, 1, 1, x }, // false
        new int[] { 0, 1, 1, x }, // false
        new int[] { 3, 1, x, x },  // true   1           
        //-------- all possible shifts:
        new int[] { 3, 1, 0, 1 },  // true   0 <=> -4          
        new int[] { 1, 3, 1, 0 },  // true   1 <=> -3          
        new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 1 },  // true   2 <=> -2          
        new int[] { 1, 0, 1, 3 },  // true   3 <=> -1            
};

const int digits = 3;
string format = new String('0', digits);
string inputAsString =
    String.Join(",", mainArray.Select(i => i.ToString(format))) + ",";
inputAsString = "," + inputAsString + inputAsString;
Console.WriteLine($"inputAsString = \"{inputAsString}\"");
foreach (int[] input in inputs) {
    string pattern =
        "," + String.Join(",", input.Select(i => i == x ? @"\d+" : i.ToString(format))) + ",";

    var match = Regex.Match(inputAsString, pattern);
    int shift = -match.Index / (digits + 1);
    if (shift <= -input.Length / 2) {
        shift += input.Length;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"match = \"{match.Value}\", success = {match.Success}, index = {match.Index}, shift = {shift}");
}
```

This version also writes some test output to the console.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does the regex also could give the number of times the pattern is shifted?

Comment: No, but it gives you the position in the string. If you format the numbers with leading zeroes, so that they have all the same length then you can calculate the shift. e.g. `String.Join(",",mainArray,Select(i => i.ToString("000"))`. Instead off calling `Regex.IsMatch` you must call `Regex.Match` or `Regex.Matches` to give you the positions.